# WordPress - Hiding email field and submit button after submitting

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, email

**Question:** 
How do I make the email field and submit button disappear after an email is submitted?

**Details:** 
My site is built on WordPress with a theme called [Edin](https://wordpress.com/themes/edin/). I implemented an email submit form using the plugin [Mail Subscribe List](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mail-subscribe-list/).
My site is: www.fytnyc.com

I appreciate any help / guidance anyone may have to offer!

Answer (score 1):

The following JQuery this is an example so you might need to change the naming for it to work, depending on what you want the following code removes the email field and button after submitting

```
jQuery('button#submit').click(function(){
//Fields you want to remove
jQuery("p.sml_email").remove();
jQuery("button#submit").remove();
});
```

I've made a JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qw51cwh9/1/ 
This codes checks if your submit is clicked upon and if that is the case it will remove the fields inside the function with `.remove();`

Comment: Thank you for your response!! Would you happen to know where I drop this jquery? Would it be in the plugin editor? I apologize for my naiveté..Really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, it would be handy to put in on the specific page where you would put the contact form, are you for instance using a page template? Put it there, on the bottom row between a `<script>` tag. I wouldn't put it in the plugin, any updates you might get then would remove the code.

Comment: The code for the contact form exists in the plugin file, but I use a shortcode in the body of the page. I tried inserting the script in the body of the page, in the front page template editor, neither of which worked. Ideas?

Comment: Hmm Well note that my code was an example, and that you should change button#submit to whatever your button is named I think it is input.btn.sml_submitbtn. But I cannot confirm for sure, are you getting any errors when checking the page?

Comment: So the code works in that now when I click the submit button the button and email fields disappear, however, the submit function no longer returns the thank you message, nor is it capturing the email. Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Okay well, that might have to be a different question, however it's probably because the removal code is before the capture/thank you message. Are these plugins or code you wrote yourself?

Comment: I am using a plugin called Mail Subscribe List. Even when I place the code in the plugin editor, after the capture/thank you message, the issue still remains. I've reached out to the plugin support over a week ago, but haven't heard anything. You would think it would be a feature / shortcode in the plugin.

Comment: Hmm I see, well nothing I can help with on the plugin side. I am not familliar with that. When going to your site it is the same as usual, could you put the code live so I can see what's going wrong? Have you also made sure that the code I gave you is _after_ your plugin code?